# How do I create a selection sort code in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, selection-sort

I'm trying to create a selection sort in at&t x64/GNU syntax. I can't understand the swap. This is some parts of my code working on the inner loop.

The selection sort in python:

```
    for I in range(len(a)-1, 0, -1):
            max = i
            for j in range(0, max):
                   if a[max] < a[j]:
                          max = j
```

Here is what I'm working in assembly:

```
    i_loop:
            mov %rsi, %rax
            dec %rax

            mov %rax, %r11

            mov $0, %rcx
            mov $0, %r13 # for test
            mov $0, %r14 # for test

    _i_loop:
            mov (%rdi, %rcx, 8), %rbx
            mov (%rdi, %rax, 8), %r12
            cmp %rbx, %r12

            jl change

            inc %rcx
            cmp %rcx, %r11
            jne _i_loop

            mov %r12, %rax
            ret

    change:
            mov %rax, %r13
            mov %rcx, %r14

            mov %rcx, %rax

            inc %rcx
            cmp %rcx, %r11
            jne _i_loop

            jmp swap

    swap:
            mov (%rdi, %r11, 8), %r12   
            mov (%rdi, %r13, 8), %rbx   
            
            push %r12
            mov %rbx, %r12
            pop %rbx
            
            mov %r12, (%rdi, %r11, 8) # error 
            mov %rbx, (%rdi, %r13, 8) # error

            mov %r12, %rax
            
            ret
```

Can you explain how swapping works in assembly language?

Comment: You `ret` at the end of `swap`, but you didn't `call` it, you just jumped to it.  It doesn't need to be a function; you should have one of the values in a register anyway to compare, so you can just store.  (You also don't need that push/mov/pop register-exchange; just store the opposite registers vs. the mov loads.  If you did want to swap registers, `xchg reg,reg` is the least bad way to do it.)

Comment: But very likely there are other problems; if your mov loads succeeded but then the stores to the same addresses segfaulted, that sounds like you have a pointer to a read-only page.  Don't try to sort read-only data.  Since you don't show a caller for this function, this isn't a [mcve] of the problem that's causing *that* (and I guess stopping you from reaching the `ret` and discovering other bugs on your own)